# issue using constructor in java

Tags: java, android, constructor

I want to pass some data between classes but i cant get it working. Getting NullPointerException at line `home.adapter.updateStatus();`

Main class

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
SocialAuthAdapter adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.TWITTER, R.drawable.button_twitter);
    }
}
```

Helper class

```
 public class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {

HomeScreen home = new HomeScreen();

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    home.adapter.updateStatus("update");
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should not create instances of your Activity classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that the adapter is not being initialised, which can only mean onCreate() isn't being invoked...

Answer (score 1):

When Activity is started for the first time only once the onCreate() method will be called.
It will not be created when you create object for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

you instantiated `HomeScreen home = new HomeScreen();` by constructor, but in your HomeScreen class, you instantiated `adapter` in a method `onCreate()`. did your HomeScreen constructor call this method?

If not, adapter is null, so you got NPE.

Answer (score 0):

You should move:

```
adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
adapter.addProvider(Provider.TWITTER, R.drawable.button_twitter);
```

to `HomeScreen` constructor like this:

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public SocialAuthAdapter adapter;

    public HomeScreen() {
        adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
        adapter.addProvider(Provider.TWITTER, R.drawable.button_twitter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your code

```
 adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener(HomeScreen.this));
```

Helper class,

```
 public class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
 private HomeScreen context;
 public ResponseListener(HomeScreen homescreen) {
    context = homescreen;

}


}
```